# Change Time Zone of NSDate

Tags: ios

I have two dates,start date and end date.In both dates ,time zone is different.

Here is example of dates : `start date - 2013-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 and end date - 2012-01-31 18:30:00 +0000`.

I want difference between this two dates and i am using this code :

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *totalDaydDfference = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit |NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:startingDate  toDate:endingDate  options:0];
return [totalDaydDfference day] + 1;
```

Now i want to see both dates in same time zone just like my start date.How can i do?please help me.

Thanking you.

Comment: `NSDate`s don't have a time zone. Where are these dates coming from?

Comment: i am getting start date from user and end date finding it using last date of month code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ever timezone it is ,the `NSDate` value remains the same .So just find the difference between tha `NSDate`s

Comment: when i try to do so, i got day difference in minus.

Comment: Your end date happens before your start date. Switch the from and to dates and you'll get the positive difference. Simple subtraction issue: 10 - 6 = 4, 6 - 10 = -4